# Existence of a set function

Tags: inequality

Consider the set S of all subsets of {1, 2, 3, 4}. Show that there exists a function h : S → [0, 1] that satisfies all following conditions:

Condition 1: h(∅) = 0
Condition 2: h({1, 2, 3, 4}) = 1
Condition 3: h(·) is monotone, i.e. that for all A ∈ S and B ∈ S such that A ⊆ B, h(A) ≤ h(B)
Condition 4: h(·) is submodular, i.e. that for all A ∈ S and B ∈ S, h(A ∪ B) ≤ h(A) + h(B) − h(A ∩ B)
Condition 5: h(·) respects the following form of symmetry.
h({1}) = h({2}) = h({3}) = h({4}) , h({1, 2}) = h({3, 4}) , h({1, 4}) = h({2, 3}) , h({1, 3}) = h({2, 4}) , h({1, 2, 3}) = h({1, 3, 4}) = h({1, 2, 4}) = h({2, 3, 4}).
Condition 6: h({1, 3}) > h({1, 4})

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. This is a critical part of my entrance into a Ph.D. program (not a Math Ph.D. program).

Comment: The symmetry conditions in condition 5 implies that there are only $5$ degrees of freedom when choosing your function. Have you tried simply to write down the inequalities between the 5 function values that come from conditions 3 and 4 and look for a solution to those?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Working on this now. @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(\emptyset)=0$, $h(A)=\frac 12$ if $|A|=1$ or $A=\{1,4\}$ or $A=\{2,3\}$, $h(A)=1$ otherwise.
Then conditions 1, 2, 3, 5 are met. To check condition 4 for $A\not\subseteq B$ and $B\not\subseteq A$, verify that $h(A\cap B)= \frac12$ can only occur if one of $h(A)$, $h(B)$ equals $1$, and $h(A\cap B)=1$ can only occur if $h(A)=h(B)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, I do have one additional question. How is condition 6 accounted for in this solution?